# ASMX + external dll

Tags: web-services, iis, dll, tfs, asmx

I am working on Silverlight client to Microsoft Team Foundation Server.  I am using an ASMX web service to make the actual calls using the TFS api.

Everything works fine when I run it with the visual studio development server, but I cannot figure out how to deploy the app to IIS.

I can get the ASMX web service to work unless it is a call that uses the TFS api.  I have tried putting all of the TFS api DLLs in like every directory that I can think of, and even installing the visual studio sdk.  Nothing works!

**UPDATE 11/15/09 7:50PM EST:**

Turns out that the TFS api was trying to create a cache at c:\Documents and Settings\Default User\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache\, and the IIS_WPG user didn't have access to do so.  Easy fix.

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing works!". Are you getting exceptions thrown? Needs more info.

Comment: 500 internal server error is shown. We aren't getting any exceptions, just that any calls to the TFS api puts out a 500 error.

Comment: Most likely cause is that you're unable to load the TFS assemblies (because Team Explorer isn't installed), or a problem authenticating with the TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way of installing the TFS API is to install Team Explorer.  You could try to GAC just the assemblies you need, but you're on your own [and technically violating the EULA]...

Other things to check:

- IIS is running in 32 bit mode
- Impersonation is working correctly
- Proxy settings

What error do you get?  Have you tried attaching a debugger to IIS?

Comment: IIS is running in 32 bit. Verified proxy and firewall settings to not be the cause. Could you elaborate on impersonation? That is something I am unfamiliar with. We have yet to attach a debugger to IIS, what should I be looking for with that?

Comment: Your service needs to use impersonation so that the user's credentials are forwarded to TFS.  Otherwise TFS will complain that it doesn't know who [your IIS service account] is.  Attaching a debugger is the easiest way to find which line of code is throwing an exception + what the state of your internal variables are at the time.